# Django Templating vs AJAX to load a small div

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

I have a Django server. The server loads a webpage with almost all static content but a few numbers must load from the database.

I'm thinking about performance/price; I can host my Django server on a fast server and render the page using Django templates. or I can host the server on a slower machine and make a static page that loads the few numbers using ajax and host the page cheaply somewhere else like *github.io*.

The latter choice will have most of the page load real quick and real cheap.

I was wondering what are the trade-offs ?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever server you decide to hire, you should always think of **reducing the server load - no matter how fast your server is**. By *reducing server load* I mean only make your server do what is **really required at the moment**.

### Let's learn something from the big players like Facebook, for instance

You log into your account and you see that you've got 5 notifications and 3 new messages plus a couple of photos and highly interesting statuses of your friends. Cool! You now click on the notifications icon to find out if *that* hot girl (forgive me if you're a girl :D) has added you to her friends list or not. As you click a big white `<div>` pops up AND you see nothing but a loading gif! The notifications do appear, but after a couple of seconds. Try doing it with a slow internet connection, and you get to adore the beauty of the loading gif for a lot more time.

### So, what do you make of it?

Facebook only made it's server *count* the number of notifications and new messages, and displayed those numbers to you. Thus reducing server load. It only displayed the notifications to you when you wanted to see them. And to load the notifications, all it took was a minimal AJAX call in which only around 10 KB of data was transferred!

Facebook does it all the time and everywhere. Consider this: Robert Downey Jr. posts a photo of himself on his Facebook page. A little while later, you see that it has got 10k+ comments. You decide to read them and click the comments button. An attractive loading gif pops up again for a little while and is soon replaced by comments. But hey, only 10 comments were loaded. What the ... Oh wait! **That's how Facebook reduces its server load - read those 10 comments first, if you want to read more, send a request again.**

Twitter does it too - **the infinite scroll**.

### Icing on the cake

This approach benefits you in two ways:

1. It reduces server load - less chances of crashing a website.
2. It decreases your website's page-load time since you'll be passing less data *i.e.* the *data required at that moment*. Thus making your website faster. (Yes, it can outrun Flash, too!)

### Food for thought

If you've got some cool technologies around such as AJAX, why not use it? Your server is not a donkey, for God's sake!

P.S. By Facebook and Twitter, I mean the engineers behind them.

Comment: This is a beautiful response to "why AJAX is good". In my case I'm talking about a number on top of my page that will need to load every time the page loads. On top of my page, I would like to say for example say x people have used this webpage and there no other dynamic content. Now, I can load the page from my server or I can let github.io to load the webpage and get that one number from my server with AJAX.

Comment: @Kiarash, in simple terms: let github.io load the webpage and get that one number for you server with AJAX. I mean it's all about saving bandwidth, reducing server load, saving disk space, increasing page-load speed. Plus you get to save some bucks if you go with github.io. Well, do the math. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well It would depend on the following:

### A. Whether you want to Display that number on Page load itself or when user clicks to see it* ?

If you want to show the the **numbers at the time of Page load** Itself than it is preferable to get them at time of Template response itself.

Why do you would want your Site Visitors to wait till those numbers populate (if the intention is to display them) ?

If it is to be displayed on User's click only then Ajax should be preferred

### B. How much Time is this Query going to take and Can the query be optimized to minimal time ?

If the Query you are making takes a Lot of time than **first effort should be made to optimize** that query to be as fast as possible,

If the query can give result in minimal time than it is **futile** to do another Request to Server via Ajax.

But if you know the Query will take a lot of Time than Ajax is fine.